# Python/MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am using the mysql connector for Python and I'm trying to run the following SQL statement via Python (Windows) - It's a .csv file:

```
sql1 = ('SET GLOBAL local_infile = "ON";')
cursor.execute(sql1)

sql2 = ('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "' + path[1:-1] + '" INTO TABLE mytable COLUMNS  TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\\r\\n" (COL0, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6) SET COL7 = "'some_data'";')
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

but when I try to execute I receive the following exception:

> 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

If I try to execute LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on mysql console, everything runs fine.

Comment: which command is the problem?  sql1 or sql2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load Data Infile is disabled by default with Connector/Python
while creating the connection set LOCAL_FILES client flag like this:

```
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag
conn = mysql.connector.connect(...., client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES])
```

Comment: It did work. I tried this once, but I forgot to add the import.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of security issues with `LOAD DATA`, so the server is really picky.  Are you logging in to localhost, not the public IP of the server? Often one IP will be granted `LOAD DATA`, but the other won't.

See [the fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each line of the file, inserting each as a row. This would be easy since you already mentioned each column is delineated by `,` and each row is delineated by newlines.

For example, assuming your table mytable had 8 string columns, (COL0 to COL7):

```
input_file = open(path[1:-1], 'r')

#Loop through the lines of the input file, inserting each as a row in mytable
for line_of_input_file in input_file:
    values_from_file = line_of_input_file.split(',', 1) #get the columns from the line read from the file

    if(len(values_from_file) == 7): #ensure that 7 columns accounted for on this line of the file
        sql_insert_row = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (" + values_from_file[0] + "," + values_from_file[1] + "," + values_from_file[2] + "," + values_from_file[3] + "," + values_from_file[4] + "," + values_from_file[5] + "," + values_from_file[6] + "," + some_data + ");"
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_row)
input_file.close()
```

Comment: Doing the `INSERT` takes a long time. I have to insert thousands of registers. That's why I choose `LOAD DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

With the MySQLdb driver:

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.constants import CLIENT
```

then along with other arguments to `MySQLdb.connect()` , pass `client_flag=CLIENT.LOCAL_FILES`

Discovered by studying the source, and then trying it out.